# Custom hibernate second level cache name lookup

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, caching

I'm using spring boot with second level cache for the entities, e.g.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "customer")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
public class Customer implements Serializable {
  ....
}
```

This is working as expected, but now I have to turn the application into a multi-tenant version. Each tenant has it's own database, where we use a `ThreadLocal` to store the current tenant and `AbstractRoutingDataSource` for routing to the tenant's database. This is working, if the 2nd level cache is off.

It would be nice to get also the 2nd level cache working. The problem seems to be the cache name, which is the FQCN for an entity. Since the cache is not tenant or database-aware, each tenant uses the same cache.

For this, we use a `ThreadLocal` for resolving the current tenant is simply accessible by

```
TenantContext.getCurrentTenant();
```

and returns the tenant name.

We use the EhCache, which is backed by the spring cache abstraction:

```
@Bean
public CacheManager cacheManager() {
    net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager cacheManager = net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.create();
    EhCacheCacheManager ehCacheManager = new EhCacheCacheManager();
    ehCacheManager.setCacheManager(cacheManager);
    return ehCacheManager;
}
```

Is it possible to intercept the generation of the cache-name, so that the current tenant name is used instead of the FQCN and each insert/lookup/evict resolves this tenant-aware-cache-name?

Comment: Probably your Hibernate is not aware that you expect it to be multitenant. Otherwise your cache would work. Did you read this first? https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/devguide/en-US/html/ch16.html

Comment: Yes, I know. We were aware of the multi-tenancy support of hibernate, but we had to solve other "problems" (e.g. with liquibase, spring data or elasticsearch...) so we could not use that and have chosen another solution. And a correct cache-name resolver would solve that...

Answer (score 0):

In order to intercept the generation of the cache-name one approach is to override the method `getCache(String name)` of the `EhCacheCacheManager` as follows:

```java
@Bean
public CacheManager cacheManager() {
    net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager cacheManager = net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.create();
    EhCacheCacheManager ehCacheManager = new EhCacheCacheManager(){
        @Override
        public Cache getCache(String name) {
            String tenantId = TenantContext.getCurrentTenant();
            return super.getCache(String.format("%s:%s", tenantId, name));
        }
    };
    ehCacheManager.setCacheManager(cacheManager);
    return ehCacheManager;
}
```